# r trycatch() not running error function

Tags: r, function, error-handling

thought I'd managed to get R's trycatch implemented properly, but trying to build a bit more functionality into my code has scuppered me... any help appreciated!

**Background:**

I'm starting on some work where we have a load of sensor data coming in from some equipment. We've identified a time when something 'interesting' happened, and I'm writing a little helper function to help me sift through all of the channels looking for ones that did something 'interesting' at that time. Eventually I'd like to automate detecting 'interesting' but for now it's just someone eyeballing it in a ggplot.

**Working Starting Point:**

The following code works great. The code tries to get data from the database, if it can't (because the channel's not yet active in the database) it just loops on to the next channel. If it succeeds it prints it up in a ggplot, and the user can eyeball it and press 'Enter' to pass on it, enter "1" to highlight it as an 'interesting channel', or enter "x" to stop and return the interesting channels so far.

```
getDataPlot <- function(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table,title="loc_id"){

  #Retrieve data from the Cassandra database
  dataframe <- getData(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table)

  #Set chart title
  if(title=="loc_id"){
    title <- loc_id
  }

  #plot results for user to look at
  print(ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=gmt_event, y=data_value)) + geom_line() + ggtitle(title))
}



runThroughChannels <- function(channelList,site_code,from,to,resolution,connection,table){
  #Set up blank dataframe to capture 'interesting' channels
  interestingChannels <- data.frame(NAME=c(),MEAS_LOC_ID=c(),UNITS=c())

  #loop through the channels
  for(i in 1:nrow(channelList)){
    loc_id <- toString(channelList$MEAS_LOC_ID[i])
    title <- paste(channelList$NAME[i]," (Chnl ",i," of ",nrow(channelList),")",sep="")

    #Try and plot the data, if fails, set inputline to 'E' as a flag to skip on
    tryCatch(
{
  getDataPlot(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table,title)
  inputline <- readline() #Waits for user input once chart is plotted
},
error=function(e){
  inputline <- "E"
})

#Handle user input
if(inputline=="x"){
  return(interestingChannels)
}else if(inputline=="1"){
  #Add this channel to the list of interesting ones
  interestingChannels <- rbind(interestingChannels,channelList[i,])
}
  }
return(interestingChannels)
}
```

It may be relevant that when I run getDataPlot for a channel that isn't active in the database yet, the error my trycatch is (apparently) successfully catching looks like this (which is expected):

```
> getDataPlot("0000000000443337","23","2013-12-04 11:00:00","2013-12-04 13:00:00","minute",casscon,"events_by_location")

 Error in seq.POSIXt(startTime, collectedData[nrow(collectedData), ]$gmt_event,  : 
  'to' must be of length 1 In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

**Bit that Doesn't Work**

A lot of the channels are just zeros, and I needn't bother the user with them when looking for something 'interesting'. So, with a flag to enable the behaviour, I'd like getDataPlot to throw an error when the values are all zeros as well as when it just can't get the data, so I tried:

```
getDataPlot <- function(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table,title="loc_id",error_if_zero=FALSE){

  #Retrieve data from the Cassandra database
  dataframe <- getData(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table)

  #Set chart title
  if(title=="loc_id"){
    title <- loc_id
  }

  #New section - throw an error if zeros only so that we skip on to the next channel
  if(error_if_zero){
    if(sum(abs(dataframe$data_value))==0){
      stop("Zeros only")
    }
  }

  #plot results for user to look at
  print(ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=gmt_event, y=data_value)) + geom_line() + ggtitle(title))
}



runThroughChannels <- function(channelList,site_code,from,to,resolution,connection,table){
  #Set up blank dataframe to capture 'interesting' channels
  interestingChannels <- data.frame(NAME=c(),MEAS_LOC_ID=c(),UNITS=c())

  #loop through the channels
  for(i in 1:nrow(channelList)){
    loc_id <- toString(channelList$MEAS_LOC_ID[i])
    title <- paste(channelList$NAME[i]," (Chnl ",i," of ",nrow(channelList),")",sep="")

    #Try and plot the data, if fails, set inputline to 'E' as a flag to skip on
    tryCatch(
      {
        getDataPlot(site_code,loc_id,from,to,resolution,connection,table,title,TRUE)
        inputline <- readline() #Waits for user input once chart is plotted
      },
      error=function(e){
        inputline <- "E"
      })

    #Handle user input
    if(inputline=="x"){
      return(interestingChannels)
    }else if(inputline=="1"){
      #Add this channel to the list of interesting ones
      interestingChannels <- rbind(interestingChannels,channelList[i,])
    }
  }
  return(interestingChannels)
}
```

But I get `Error: object 'inputline' not found` and running through it with debug it looks like the `getDataPlot` line runs in my `tryCatch`, but when that stops it just skips over to `if(inputline=="x")`

**What I've tried**

Rather infuriatingly, putting a hacky `if(!exists(inputline)){inputline <- "E"}` catch in before `if(inputline=="x")` yields `Error in exists(inputline) : object 'inputline' not found`. The ironic humour in this error, of course, was not lost on me, but it did prompt a rather rapid turn to StackOverflow!!!

Comment: Try defining `inputline <- "E"` before the `tryCatch` block.  That way the variable will always be defined, but will be overwritten if you actually input something through `readline`.

Comment: Also, in the future, please try to simplify your problem as much as possible so it is easier for people here to get to the bottom of.  You will find that the simplification process itself will often give you the answers you are looking for.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks! That workaround worked nicely... might have spotted it if I'd cleared out some of the gumph :)

Comment: @BrodieG Still not sure why it doesn't execute my error block though...

Comment: it does execute the error block, but the changes to variables don't persist. verify this by printing something (or using <<- if you're really careful).
Also, the syntax is `exists("inputline")`

Comment: Probably a few years too late. But I think your error function needs a return statement :)